# how validate fields using jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i am newbie in jquery. i searched in google and i got [Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). but it's not working. i have attached jquery.validate.js in my header part.

**my code looks like...**

```
  <form action="" method="" id="contact">
            <div class="form-group"">
                <label> Your Name </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name" id="firstname" required="" minlength="5"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Your E-mail </label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="email"/>
            </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Send</button>
 </form>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#contact').validate({
     success: function(label){
    label.addClass("has-success").text("ok");
    }
  });
</script>
```

but it's not validating my field... Can anyone say how to use it? i know i am doing something wrong here but i am newbie so...

Comment: Where is the submit button?

Comment: sorry i forgot to copy that

Answer (score 1):

Try using document ready instruction:

```
$(function(){
   $('#contact').validate();
});
```

it works: http://jsfiddle.net/RQMaV/15/

Comment: i just put $('#contact').validate() in downside of form and it worked. Thanks a lot... one more question i am adding bootstrap 3.0 has-success class when it's success but it's not taking that class... pls check my edited code...

Answer (score 1):

Did you include jquery-plugin validation.js file in your project directory?? If no then you need to include http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/validation.js

Comment: i have downloaded files from above given link. in that they have given jquery.validate.js that i included.

Comment: See the js fiddle link..http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/RQMaV/ might be this will help you

Comment: i just put $('#contact').validate() in downside of form and it worked. Thanks a lot... one more question i am adding bootstrap 3.0 has-success class when it's success but it's not taking that class... pls check my edited code...

Answer (score 1):

The submit button is essencial since it fires the validate function:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) { // this line is important
    form.submit(); // with this line the validate function gets fired
  }
 });
```

perhaps you should also try following:

– make sure your jquery library is correctly embedded in your document

– make sure your validation.js is in the correct folder

Comment: i just put $('#contact').validate() in downside of form and it worked. Thanks a lot... one more question i am adding bootstrap 3.0 has-success class when it's success but it's not taking that class... pls check my edited code...